# How to make span snap to bottom of div (multiple divs)

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have code in which I need to create three images under each other, with  text span.
Problem is, that I can't set "top" value for each image relatively to each image (for example, all images are 150px tall, so "top" value would be 130px for each span, not 130, 290 and so on...)
My HTML code:

```
<div class="obrazekvmenu" style="float:left; margin-bottom:10px; left:-2px;">
<a href="#">
<img class="obrazekvmenu" src="https://asset.msi.com/global/picture/image/feature/multimeda/mouse/DS300/ds300Banner.jpg" style="display:inline-block; width:440px; height:185px;"/></a>
<span class="photoh20"><h2 class="entry-title" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 16px;"><a class="photoa" href="#" rel="bookmark">MSI</a></h2></span>
</div>
<div class="obrazekvmenu" style="float:left; margin-bottom:10px; left:-2px;">
<a href="#">
<img class="obrazekvmenu" src="https://asset.msi.com/global/picture/image/feature/multimeda/mouse/DS300/ds300Banner.jpg" style="display:inline-block; width:440px; height:185px;"/></a>
<span class="photoh21"><h2 class="entry-title" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 16px;"><a class="photoa" href="#" rel="bookmark">MSI</a></h2></span>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.obrazekvmenu:hover > .photoh20{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,1),rgba(51,52,51,1));
}
.obrazekvmenu:hover > .photoh21{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,1),rgba(51,52,51,1));
}
span.photoh20{
text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}
span.photoh21{
text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}
.sidebarimage{
top:-3px;
}
span.photoh20 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
top:147px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,0.7),rgba(51,52,51,.7));
    width: 103.338%;
}
.obrazekvmenu{
width:310px;
height:185px;
}
span.photoh21 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
top:147px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,0.7),rgba(51,52,51,.7));
    width: 103.338%;
}
```

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/g1zn2nm6/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="obrazekvmenu" style="float:left; margin-bottom:50px; left:-2px;">
<a href="#">
 <img class="obrazekvmenu" src="https://asset.msi.com/global/picture/image/feature/multimeda/mouse/DS300/ds300Banner.jpg" style="display:inline-block; width:440px; height:185px;" />
</a>
<span class="photoh20"><h2 class="entry-title" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 16px;">
 <a class="photoa" href="#" rel="bookmark">MSI</a></h2>
</span>
</div>
<div class="obrazekvmenu" style="float:left; margin-bottom:10px;    left:-2px;">
<a href="#">
 <img class="obrazekvmenu" src="https://asset.msi.com/global/picture/image/feature/multimeda/mouse/DS300/ds300Banner.jpg" style="display:inline-block; width:440px; height:185px;" />
</a>
<span class="photoh21"><h2 class="entry-title" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 16px;">
<a class="photoa" href="#" rel="bookmark">MSI</a></h2>
</span>
</div>
```

and In your css

```
.obrazekvmenu:hover > .photoh20 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(51,    52, 51, 1));
 }
.obrazekvmenu{display:block}
.obrazekvmenu:hover > .photoh21 {
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(51, 52, 51, 1));
 }

 span.photoh20 {
 text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
 }

 span.photoh21 {
 text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
 }

 .sidebarimage {
  top: -3px;
  }

  span.photoh20 {  
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgba(51, 52, 51, .7));
  width: 103.338%;
  }

 .obrazekvmenu {
  width: 310px;
  height: 185px;
  }

  span.photoh21 { 
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgba(51, 52, 51, .7));
   width: 103.338%;
  }
```

I hope this will help you to solve your issue

Comment: instead of top value use 'margin-top:-50px;' .